# Form ajax php not work with data serialize with action empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

This form originally operated with process.php in action form and this work very well.

But  when I want to work in the same page with action empty, ajax not work (php no receiving data from ajax form)

When I change. data:

```
form.serialize(),
```

to

```
data: request,
```

The form work, php receiving data from ajax but I have a problem, the form refresh page.

Ajax source

```
<script>
//if form is valid
        else {
            loading.show();
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: form.attr('method'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(){
                    showNotice('success');
                    form.get(0).reset();
                    loading.hide();
                }
            });
        }

        return false; //this stops submission off the form and also stops browsers showing default error messages

    });
</script>
```

Html form

```
 <form method="post" action="" class="mailform">




                  <button name="submit" type="submit" class="zbtn">Sumbit Message</button>

            </form>
```

Code Php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    //Here syntax for the form 

    //if this is not an ajax request
    if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){
        //set session variables
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;


    }
}
?>
```

¿As I can run this form via ajax without refreshing the page?

Note: This is the orinal form (demo) work with process.php in action:
http://goo.gl/cSCBqN

Comment: There is nothing in your form to serialize.

Comment: what is form variable? Have you decladerd form variable as var form = $('form')

Comment: Hi there: //set global variables and cache DOM elements for reuse later
 var form = $('#contact-form').find('form'),
  formElements = form.find('input[type!="submit"],textarea'),
  formSubmitButton = form.find('[type="submit"]'),
  errorNotice = $('#errors'),
  successNotice = $('#success'),
  loading = $('#loading'),
  errorMessages = {
   required: ' is a required field',
   email: 'You have not entered a valid email address for the field: ',
   minlength: ' must be greater than '
  }

Comment: The source comple javascript is: http://goo.gl/dmF3eY